# How setEntity method works in java

Tags: java

I am develop a java program which will send my file in whole junk of file to my server for scanning via certain url `http://ServerUrl:portNumber/file` but i am getting this error in my eclipse compiler

```
The method setEntity(HttpEntity) in the type HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase is not applicable for the arguments (InputStream).
```

Is it because Java Inputstream cant use together with setEntity method? I cant read the file byte by byte because the file will not only have document file,it's might have .exe file as well. 
 Here is my source code

```
public class SentFile {

public static void main(String [] args) {
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.25:8008/file");
      File file = new File("testScanFile.txt");
      InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
      post.setEntity(is);
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
      String line = "";
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(line);
      }
     }

}
```

Comment: Yes, an ``InputStream`` is not the same as ``HttpEntity``. What have to tried to resolve this?

Comment: there is a file in my pc, i want to use java code to send it over to the server url for scanning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

[FileEntity](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/FileEntity.html) will work here

```
post.setEntity(new FileEntity(file));
```

Comment: i had add in your code, its show me no error now but it's show me some package mssing.Do you have any recommend website for me to download the package ?

Comment: Well, I think it should be from `org.apache.http` only this is the import statement `import org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity;`.